# Defining a matrix with a recurrent sequence

Tags: matrix

How can a matrix `A[n]` of size $2^n \times 2^n$ be defined 
given that

```
A[1]= {{1, -1}, {1, 1}}
```

and for $n \ge 1$,

```
A[n + 1] = {{A[n], -A[n]}, {A[n], A[n]}}
```

I tried to use `SparseArray` and assigned the values, but it's limited to set of values I can assign, which doesn't work. Also, I thought to try this : setting a size `s= 2^n` and then using it in a array `x = Array[n, {s, s}]`, but I get stuck on how to set the elements to 1 and -1.

Can you please guide me in right direction or tell me if I'm going in the wrong direction?

Comment: Look up `ArrayFlatten`

Comment: But how can the sequence be defined? Have to do something with 2^n-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A[1] = {{1, -1}, {1, 1}}
A[n_] := A[n] = ArrayFlatten[{{A[n - 1], -A[n - 1]}, {A[n - 1], A[n - 1]}}]
(* {{1, -1}, {1, 1}} *)

A[5] // MatrixPlot
```

[image]

References:

- [`ArrayFlatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayFlatten.html)
- [Function that remember their values](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html)

Answer (score 1):

`KroneckerProduct[]` is the more natural function to use for generating Walsh-like matrices:

```
mat = {{1, -1}, {1, 1}};
amat[n_Integer?NonNegative] := Nest[KroneckerProduct[mat, #] &, mat, n - 1]

MatrixPlot[amat[5]]
```

[image: Walsh matrix]